# Flutter how do i show a video in alertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to show a video in a alertDialog widget but i don't know how to show it in a alertDialog widget. here is my code.

```
class ResultScreen extends StatelessWidget {
static const routeResult = '/result-screen';
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('The Result'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        elevation: 0.0),
    drawer: SideManu(),
    body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Background(),
        MoodText(),
        ShowLevel(),
        ActivityText(),
        ActivityClip()
      ]))
    ]));
 }
}
```

this is my code for button to open a video

```
class ActivityClip extends StatelessWidget {
final List<String> numbers = [
  'Soft Music',
  'Meditation',
  'Pray',
  'Breathing',
  'Relex'
];
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, top: 350),
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
    child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: numbers.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
              width: 200,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.brown,
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                    numbers[index].toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
                  )),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                 activityVideo(context);
                 //alertDialog to show a video
                },
              ));
        }));  
 }
```

This is my code for a alertDialog. This dialog i plan to show a video clip.

```
void activityVideo(BuildContext context){
var alertDialog = AlertDialog(
  title: Text("videoclip"),
  actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              child: Text('Rate'),
              onPressed: () {
                rateVideo(context);
              }),
              FlatButton(
              child: Text('Finish'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }),
        ],
);
showDialog(context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context){
  return alertDialog;
}
);
}
```

Cloud you show me an example the way to show the video. Or if there are any good ways to show the video instead this way you can suggest me. Thank you so much.

here is a picture of my app to make you clearer. This is my page if you click to activity it will popup the video cilp.

[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV31a.jpg)

This is a dialog that i plan to show a video.

[alertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8f7y.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlertDialog has a content field that you can easily send a widget to it.check document for a simple example. Furthermore, for showing the video you use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package. for a simple tutorial check [this post](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video) published by flutter team.