# How can we play video in Alert Dialogue Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, video, video-player

To play video within the alert dialog I am using the below code. But Video is not playing. Is it possible to play video within the Alert Dialog? Does anyone has a solution to this please share it with me.

```js
Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  VideoPlayerController _controller;

_controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
                                  video_base_url+videoUrl,
                                );

                                // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
                                _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

                                // Use the controller to loop the video.
                                _controller.setLooping(true);

                                // If the video is playing, pause it.
                                if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                                  _controller.pause();
                                } else {
                                  // If the video is paused, play it.
                                  _controller.play();
                                }
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                ContainerResponsive(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-50,
                                height: 150,
                                child: FutureBuilder(
                                  future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                                      // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                                      // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
                                      return AspectRatio(
                                        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                                        // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                                        child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                                      // loading spinner.
                                      return const Center(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
                                    }
                                  },
                                )

                              ),
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how do i show a video in alertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174864/flutter-how-do-i-show-a-video-in-alertdialog)

Comment: Yeah ... But I am using it the same way. But my video is stopped at the first frame.

Comment: do you set autoplay to true?

Comment: Yes, I added it.

Comment: If I initialize player in InitState it is working. But my requirement is when I click on the gridview item alert dialog will open. Then I will click the play button.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new Stateful widget class like this for video player , initialized video player controller and video player widget here

```html
import 'package:approved/src/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? url;
  final bool? play;

  const VideoWidget({@required this.url, @required this.play});
  @override
  _VideoWidgetState createState() => _VideoWidgetState();
}

class _VideoWidgetState extends State<VideoWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void>? _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url!);
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
      setState(() {});
    });

    if (widget.play!) {
      _controller.play();
      _controller.setLooping(true);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(VideoWidget oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.play != widget.play) {
      if (widget.play!) {
        _controller.play();
        _controller.setLooping(true);
      } else {
        _controller.pause();
      }
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return VideoPlayer(_controller);
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      
    ]);
  }
}
```

Now you can use this **widget** anywhere you have to just pass the video url and playing parameter true/false.

Like I am using in **showDialog** method

```html
playVideo(
    BuildContext context,
    
  ) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                  child: VideoWidget(url: url, play: true)));
        });
  }
```